# Polynomial Addition that contains 3 variables in C

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, polynomials

This was given as a coding exercise for us. I've seen many examples around but they mostly use only one variable `x`. For this one, the two polynomials could contain at most 3 variables.

Let me explain the inputs. First line denotes the number of terms (non-zero coefficients) `n` for the first polynomial. The next `n` lines represent every term of the first polynomial in the form `x exponent` `y exponent` `z exponent` `coefficient`. Example: `4x⁵y⁴z²` would be `5 4 2 4`. The next line would be the same thing, but it will be for the second polynomial. We are to return the resulting sum and print them line by line in canonical order. The coefficient is a real number that may be signed or unsigned. I will provide a test case.

I've researched and formulated all the tasks. In fact, the test case that I will be providing can be answered correctly by my code. My problem is, there are hidden cases where my code gives wrong answers, and I am starting to think that my algorithm missed something.

Anyway, here is my whole code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<string.h>

struct Node
{

    float coeff;
    int powX;
    int powY;
    int powZ;
    struct Node* next;
};


void readPolynomial(struct Node** poly)
{
    struct Node* temp = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    *poly = temp;

    int terms;
    fscanf(stdin, "%d", &terms);
    getchar();

    char entry[999999];
    char *splitter;
    for(int i = 0; i < terms; i++)
    {
        fgets(entry, sizeof(entry), stdin);
        splitter = strtok(entry," ");
        temp->powX = atoi(splitter);
        splitter = strtok(NULL, " ");
        temp->powY = atoi(splitter);
        splitter = strtok(NULL, " ");
        temp->powZ = atoi(splitter);
        splitter = strtok(NULL, " ");
        temp->coeff = atof(splitter);
        temp->next = NULL;
        if(i != terms-1)
        {
            temp->next = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
            temp = temp->next;
            temp->next = NULL;
        }
    }
}

int compareTerms(const struct Node *a, const struct Node *b)
{
    int cmp;

    cmp = (a->powX > b->powX) - (a->powX < b->powX);
    if (cmp != 0) {
        return cmp;
    }
    cmp = (a->powY > b->powY) - (a->powY < b->powY);
    if (cmp != 0) {
        return cmp;
    }
    cmp = (a->powZ > b->powZ) - (a->powZ < b->powZ);
    return cmp;
}

void sortPolynomialTerms(struct Node **poly)
{
    struct Node *head;
    unsigned int sublen;

    head = *poly;
    if (!head) {

        return;
    }

    sublen = 1;
    while (1) {
        struct Node *tail;
        struct Node *p;
        struct Node *q;
        struct Node *e;
        unsigned int plen;
        unsigned int qlen;
        unsigned int merges;
        unsigned int i;

        p = head;
        head = NULL;
        tail = NULL;
        merges = 0;
        while (p) {
            merges++;
            q = p;
            plen = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < sublen; i++) {
                plen++;
                q = q->next;
                if (!q) {
                    break;
                }
            }

            qlen = plen;

            while (plen || (qlen && q)) {
                if (!plen || (qlen && q && compareTerms(p, q) < 0)) {
                    e = q;
                    q = q->next;
                    qlen--;
                } else {
                    e = p;
                    p = p->next;
                    plen--;
                }
                if (tail) {
                    tail->next = e;
                } else {
                    head = e;
                }
                tail = e;
            }

            p = q;
        }
        tail->next = NULL;

        if (merges <= 1) {
            break;
        }

        sublen *= 2;
    }

    *poly = head;
}

void printPolynomial(const struct Node *poly)
{
    while (poly)
    {
        if(poly->coeff != 0)
        {
                printf("%d %d %d %.3f\n", poly->powX, poly->powY, poly->powZ, poly->coeff);
        }
        poly = poly->next;
    }
}

void canonicalPolynomial(struct Node **poly)
{
    sortPolynomialTerms(poly);
    printPolynomial(*poly);
}

void addPolynomials(struct Node** result, struct Node* first, struct Node* second)
{
    struct Node* temp = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    temp->next = NULL;
    *result = temp;
    while(first && second)
    {
        if(compareTerms(first, second) < 0)
        {
            temp->coeff = second->coeff;
            temp->powX = second->powX;
            temp->powY = second->powY;
            temp->powZ = second->powZ;
            second = second->next;

        }
        else if(compareTerms(first, second) > 0)
        {
            temp->coeff = first->coeff;
            temp->powX = first->powX;
            temp->powY = first->powY;
            temp->powZ = first->powZ;
            first = first->next;
        }
        else
        {
            temp->coeff = first->coeff + second->coeff;
            temp->powX = first->powX;
            temp->powY = first->powY;
            temp->powZ = first->powZ;
            first = first->next;
            second = second->next;
        }
        if(first && second)
        {
            temp->next = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
            temp = temp->next;
            temp->next = NULL;
        }
    }
    while(first || second)
    {
        temp->next = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
        temp = temp->next;
        temp->next = NULL;

        if(second)
        {
            temp->coeff = second->coeff;
            temp->powX = second->powX;
            temp->powY = second->powY;
            temp->powZ = second->powZ;
            second = second->next;
        }

        else if(first)
        {
            temp->coeff = first->coeff;
            temp->powX = first->powX;
            temp->powY = first->powY;
            temp->powZ = first->powZ;
            first = first->next;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    struct Node* first = NULL;
    struct Node* second = NULL;
    struct Node* result = NULL;

    readPolynomial(&first);
    readPolynomial(&second);
    addPolynomials(&result, first, second);
    canonicalPolynomial(&result);
    return 0;
}
```

Test Case:

```
3
1 6 0 -7
0 7 0 -6
7 0 0 1
5
1 0 1 9
0 7 0 -2
5 3 2 4
1 2 3 4
1 3 0 3
```

Expected Output:

```
7 0 0 1.000
5 3 2 4.000
1 6 0 -7.000
1 3 0 3.000
1 2 3 4.000
1 0 1 9.000
0 7 0 -8.000
```

Explanation:

```
     x⁷           - 7xy⁶                       - 6y⁷
 +        4x⁵y³z²        + 3xy³ + 4xy²z³ + 9xz - 2y⁷

 =   x⁷ + 4x⁵y⁴z² - 7xy⁶ + 3xy³ + 4xy²z³ + 9xz - 8y⁷
```

Initially, I think there is a problem in my `addPolynomial` function. I just took it off from the example codes for Polynomial Addition of one variable and made some revisions.

`checkTerms` traverses the whole Polynomial and adds adjacent terms if they have the same degrees.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<string.h>

struct Node
{

    float coeff;
    int powX;
    int powY;
    int powZ;
    struct Node* next;
};


void readPolynomial(struct Node** poly)
{
    struct Node* temp = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    *poly = temp;

    int terms;
    fscanf(stdin, "%d", &terms);
    getchar();

    char entry[30];
    char *splitter;
    for(int i = 0; i < terms; i++)
    {
        fgets(entry, sizeof(entry), stdin);
        splitter = strtok(entry," ");
        temp->powX = atoi(splitter);
        splitter = strtok(NULL, " ");
        temp->powY = atoi(splitter);
        splitter = strtok(NULL, " ");
        temp->powZ = atoi(splitter);
        splitter = strtok(NULL, " ");
        temp->coeff = atof(splitter);
        temp->next = NULL;
        if(i != terms-1)
        {
            temp->next = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
            temp = temp->next;
            temp->next = NULL;
        }
    }
}

int compareTerms(const struct Node *a, const struct Node *b)
{
    int cmp;

    cmp = (a->powX > b->powX) - (a->powX < b->powX);
    if (cmp != 0) {
        return cmp;
    }
    cmp = (a->powY > b->powY) - (a->powY < b->powY);
    if (cmp != 0) {
        return cmp;
    }
    cmp = (a->powZ > b->powZ) - (a->powZ < b->powZ);
    return cmp;
}

void sortPolynomialTerms(struct Node **poly)
{
    struct Node *head;
    unsigned int sublen;

    head = *poly;
    if (!head) {

        return;
    }

    sublen = 1;
    while (1) {
        struct Node *tail;
        struct Node *p;
        struct Node *q;
        struct Node *e;
        unsigned int plen;
        unsigned int qlen;
        unsigned int merges;
        unsigned int i;

        p = head;
        head = NULL;
        tail = NULL;
        merges = 0;
        while (p) {
            merges++;
            q = p;
            plen = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < sublen; i++) {
                plen++;
                q = q->next;
                if (!q) {
                    break;
                }
            }

            qlen = plen;

            while (plen || (qlen && q)) {
                if (!plen || (qlen && q && compareTerms(p, q) < 0)) {
                    e = q;
                    q = q->next;
                    qlen--;
                } else {
                    e = p;
                    p = p->next;
                    plen--;
                }
                if (tail) {
                    tail->next = e;
                } else {
                    head = e;
                }
                tail = e;
            }

            p = q;
        }
        tail->next = NULL;

        if (merges <= 1) {
            break;
        }

        sublen *= 2;
    }

    *poly = head;
}

void printPolynomial(const struct Node *poly)
{
    while (poly)
    {
        if(poly->coeff != 0)
        {
                printf("%d %d %d %.3f\n", poly->powX, poly->powY, poly->powZ, poly->coeff);
        }
        poly = poly->next;
    }
}

void canonicalPolynomial(struct Node **poly)
{
    sortPolynomialTerms(poly);
    printPolynomial(*poly);
}

void checkTerms(struct Node* poly)
{
    while(poly)
    {
        if(poly->next != NULL)
        {
            if(compareTerms(poly, poly->next) == 0)
            {
                poly->coeff = poly->coeff + poly->next->coeff;
                poly->next = poly->next->next;
            }
        }
        poly = poly->next;
    }
}


void addPolynomials(struct Node** result, struct Node* first, struct Node* second)
{
    struct Node* temp = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    temp->next = NULL;
    *result = temp;
    while(first && second)
    {
        if(compareTerms(first, second) < 0)
        {
            temp->coeff = second->coeff;
            temp->powX = second->powX;
            temp->powY = second->powY;
            temp->powZ = second->powZ;
            second = second->next;

        }
        else if(compareTerms(first, second) > 0)
        {
            temp->coeff = first->coeff;
            temp->powX = first->powX;
            temp->powY = first->powY;
            temp->powZ = first->powZ;
            first = first->next;
        }
        else
        {
            temp->coeff = first->coeff + second->coeff;
            temp->powX = first->powX;
            temp->powY = first->powY;
            temp->powZ = first->powZ;
            first = first->next;
            second = second->next;
        }
        if(first && second)
        {
            temp->next = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
            temp = temp->next;
            temp->next = NULL;
        }
    }
    while(first || second)
    {
        temp->next = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
        temp = temp->next;
        temp->next = NULL;

        if(second)
        {
            temp->coeff = second->coeff;
            temp->powX = second->powX;
            temp->powY = second->powY;
            temp->powZ = second->powZ;
            second = second->next;
        }

        else if(first)
        {
            temp->coeff = first->coeff;
            temp->powX = first->powX;
            temp->powY = first->powY;
            temp->powZ = first->powZ;
            first = first->next;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    struct Node* first = NULL;
    struct Node* second = NULL;
    struct Node* result = NULL;

    readPolynomial(&first);
    readPolynomial(&second);
    sortPolynomialTerms(&first);
    checkTerms(&first);
    sortPolynomialTerms(&second);
    checkTerms(&second);
    addPolynomials(&result, first, second);
    canonicalPolynomial(&result);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I see a lot of `malloc`s, but I may have missed all the corresponding `free`s. Are there any in your real code? `char entry[999999];` this seems quite big for a variable with automatic storage duration, is your input that big?

Comment: I'm just assuming that the coefficient (or even the exponents) is a huge number, but I guess 999999 is impossibly huge. Either way, changing it to `char entry[30]` still cannot get the hidden test cases right.

Comment: why do u use a list? Just create an array for `struct None[terms]`. Load data, `realloc` to `struct None[terms + terms2]`, load rest of data,  `qsort()` with `compareTerms()`, accumulate duplicates and print result. Code will be short, O(N logN), and very cache-friendly

Comment: Do you mean to use `realloc` in `char entry`? I'm sorry I don't understand. Coming from a Python class, we're still new to this memory allocation concept.

Comment: You probably need to sort the terms of each polynomial before you add them (i.e. `sortPolynomialTerms(&first);` `sortPolynomialTerms(&second);` `addPolynomials(&result, first, second);`). Also, are the terms in each input polynomial guaranteed to have a unique combination of exponents? (E.g. `2` `1 2 3 -2` `1 2 3 3` has terms with identical exponents. Is that allowed?)

Comment: @IanAbbott yeah the sort before addition idea solved 2 test cases. There's one left. As for your second question. Do you mean terms with the same degrees (not necessarily the same coefficient)? If so, I would have to ask that first. But for the code I provided, it does not check terms with the same degrees. That could be a possible reason.

Comment: Yes I meant terms with the same degrees in the same polynomial. If those exist, one option would be to not bother sorting `first` and `second`, copy all the terms from `first` and `second` into the `result` polynomial, sort the terms in the `result` polynomial (so all the terms of the same degree will be adjacent), then loop through the `result` looking for adjacent terms of the same degree and combining them into a single term (unlinking and freeing the no longer needed terms in the process).

Comment: By the term copy, do you mean add them to `result`, then sort them after? Or should I create a new function to literally copy `first` and `second` to `result`?

Comment: I created a function `checkTerms` which checks adjacent terms in the Polynomial. What I did was, I sorted both polynomials `first` and `second`, then I used `checkTerms` to `first`, then to `second` to sum them all up respectively, then I continued with `addPolynomials`. Result stays the same, I am missing the last hidden test case. You can see my `checkTerms` function in OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it could be written in a much concise manner. Could you please try with this code?
My approach is quite similar to the one by @tstanisl.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<float.h>

static int comparefn(const void *a, const void *b)
{
  const double *l= (const double *) a;
  const double *r= (const double *) b;
  for(int i= 0; i< 3; ++i) {
    if(l[i]< r[i]) { return -1; }
    if(l[i]> r[i]) { return 1; }
    if(l[0]== r[0]) { continue; }
  }
  return 0;
}

double *data= NULL;
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int n1= 0;
  scanf("%d", &n1);
  data= malloc(sizeof(double)* n1* 4);
  int i= 0;
  for(; i< n1; ++i) {
    scanf("%lf %lf %lf %lf", data+ i* 4, data+ i* 4+ 1, data+ i* 4+ 2, data+ i* 4+ 3);
  }

  int n2= 0;
  scanf("%d", &n2);
  data= realloc(data, sizeof(double)* (n1+ n2)* 4);
  for(; i< n1+ n2; ++i) {
    scanf("%lf %lf %lf %lf", data+ i* 4, data+ i* 4+ 1, data+ i* 4+ 2, data+ i* 4+ 3);
  }

  qsort(data, ((size_t) (n1+ n2)), sizeof(double)* 4, &comparefn);
  for(i= 1; i< n1+ n2; ++i) {
    if(0== comparefn(data+ i* 4, data+ (i- 1)* 4)) {
      data[i* 4+ 3]+= data[(i- 1)* 4+ 3]; data[(i- 1)* 4+ 3]= 0.0;
    }
  }
  for(i= n1+ n2- 1; i> -1; --i) {
    if(fabs(data[i* 4+ 3])> DBL_EPSILON) {
      printf("%g %g %g %.3lf\n", data[i* 4], data[i* 4+ 1], data[i* 4+ 2], data[i* 4+ 3]);
    }
  }

  if(NULL!= data) {
    free(data);
    data= NULL;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use lists. As the size of introduced polynomial is given in advance it is possible to allocate a sufficient. Next use `realloc()` to load the other polynomial.
There is a problem with definition of zero coefficient. The precision should be specified. I assumed it is 0.

The problem can be solved in phases:

- read size of 1st polynomial
- alloc array
- load 1st polynomial
- read size of 2nd poly
- realloc array to fit both polynomials
- read 2nd poly
- sort terms to ensure that all terms with the same exponents are neighbours
- accumulate chunks of consecutive terms with same exponents
- print result

The code. Error handling is omitted.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct term {
    int x, y, z;
    double coef;
};

struct term load_term() {
    struct term T;
    scanf("%d %d %d %lf", &T.x, &T.y, &T.z, &T.coef);
    return T;
}

int term_cmp(const void *a_, const void *b_) {
    const struct term *a = a_, *b = b_;
    if (a->x != b->x) return b->x - a->x;
    if (a->y != b->y) return b->y - a->y;
    return b->z - a->z;
}

int main() {
    int n = 0, m;

    // load first polynomial
    scanf("%d", &m);
    struct term *P = malloc(m * sizeof *P);
    while (m--) P[n++] = load_term();

    // load second polynomial
    scanf("%d", &m);
    P = realloc(P, (n + m) * sizeof *P);
    while (m--) P[n++] = load_term();

    // sort by x,y,z exponents
    qsort(P, n, sizeof *P, term_cmp);

    // merge
    int n2 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        if (n2 > 0 && term_cmp(&P[n2 - 1], &P[i]) == 0) {
            // as long as exponents are the same as the last
            // accumulate coefficients to the last term
            P[n2 - 1].coef += P[i].coef;
        } else {
            // start a new term
            P[n2++] = P[i];
        }
    }

    // print accumulated polynomial of size `n2`
    for (int i = 0; i < n2; ++i)
           if (P[i].coef != 0)
        printf("%d %d %d %.3lf\n", P[i].x, P[i].y, P[i].z, P[i].coef);

    free(P);
}
```

Comment: Your solution is indeed shorter, but it fails 3 hidden cases. I modified it a bit to skip printing sum terms with 0 coefficients (Ex. `5 3 2 0` or `0x⁵y³z²`). Now, just like my code, it only fails in the last hidden case.

Comment: @lambduh good catch. Are you sure that the coefficient must be float. Maybe it can be int? Otherwise one must compare result with 0 what may be vunerable to rounding errors. What is the last hidden case?. Empty polynomial?

Comment: It was mentioned that the coefficient **is a real number that may be signed or unsigned**. To my understanding, that is a `float` data type? It was also mentioned that for the output, the coefficient must be **up to three decimal places**. Unfortunately, there are no hints about the hidden cases.

Comment: @lambduh, can u quote the exact wordings describing the task to solve?

Comment: **Input Format:** We assume that our input is always a polynomial on three variables (x,y,z). Two polynomials are read from input. Each polynomial P is represented as follows: **(1)** The first line denotes the number of non-zero terms P. **(2)** The succeeding lines represent every term in P. **(3)** Each line representing a term is composed of four values: the first three are non-negative integers (representing the exponents of x,y and z, respectively), the last term represents the coefficient. Note that the coefficient is a real number that may be signed or unsigned.

Comment: **Output Format:** The output should show the polynomial resulting from adding the two input polynomials. The polynomial should be output in canonical form. Each term is given in a separate line. Each line representing a term follows the same format as in input. For the output, print the coefficient up to three decimal places.

Comment: @lambdub, I see now. Float or maybe even double must be used. What is the definition of canonical form? Does coefficient 1e-6 count as zero, it will be printed as 0.000 but it is not zero?

Comment: So the question is, do we round up or down? Is that what you're asking?

Comment: @lambduh Due to rounding a sum '0.1+0.2-0.3' will not be zero. Should a term be printed? If it is negative then '-0.000' will be printed, is it ok?. My question is: under what conditions the final term is printed or not printed

Comment: I will have to ask that. But right now, I built my code and modified yours to skip those values in printing.

Comment: Since we're checking if the coefficient is equal to 0 at the printing stage, what if we check them right after we sum them up, then if it is equal to 0, we remove them in the stack?